# Get user id from wp_usermeta table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have stored the certain term ids in wp_usermeta table.
i want to get the user id where the term id match with the user meta key 'location' value.
i have tried it with below query but it is doing nothing.

```
global $wpdb;
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='location' AND meta_value LIKE %s",'%'.$term->term_id.'%');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this, you are not passing the value correctly

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE
meta_key='location' AND meta_value LIKE '%s,%".$term->term_id."%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using a sql query? i think this will do what you want exactly :

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'location', 'meta_value' => 'ANY' ) );

foreach ($user_query as $user) {
    $user->ID; // the the user id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Yes it is a reason to use sql query.
Actually I wanted to get all the terms with post relevant to each author on custom taxonomy page and the main reason is that the authors are bind with specific term by admin.
for example i have a term Texas when click on Texas it will go to taxonomy page and will get all the terms related to its author.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Here is my solution. if someone needed.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
    $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='location' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE %s", '%' . $term->term_id . '%'));
```